# Timer with two intervals for execution of tasks

Tags: c#, timer

I have a c# windows service with a timer that executes a process every 5 minutes.

I don't want to create other process to execute a task every 30 minutes, so is it possible within the same timer timer_Elapsed event to do that logic? any clue?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: I'm not 100% certain why you just aren't using scheduled tasks.

Comment: Keep a count, then every 6 times execute Task B and reset the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just use a counter and check it against `6`(30000/5000) and reset it back to zero when done.

```
private int counter = 0;
private void TimerCallback()
{
    counter++;
    if(counter >=6)
    {
        //Your 30 seconds code here
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using **2** timers?

Answer (score 1):

You could increment a variable every time the timer elapses, and when that variable reaches 6, you reset it to 0 and execute your 'once every 30 minute' code.  Also, creating a new (winform) timer does not create a new thread as far as I know.

```
int TimerVariable=0;
TimerEvent(object sender,eventargs e)
{
    TimerVariable++;
    if(TimverVariable>=6)
    {
        //Execute the once every 30 min code
    }
    //Execute the once every 5 min code.
}
```